# How do I plot between 2 variables in a summation equation?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Python and using Jupyter notebook.

Following is the summation equation that I have: $$y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} a_{i}y(t-i)$$

How can I plot between variables y and t by formulating this summation equation?

$a_{i}$ is a constant but varies on every iteration. Any value of $a_{i}$ can be assumed in this case. Please give your opinions on this.

Comment: Are you sure the expression is specified correctly?  One would need to define a valid range for t and values for y(t) where the summation is not well defined.